# Gitlab SAML logout issue

Tags: gitlab, saml

I have the old VM that running the enterprise version of Gitlab.
This version of Gitlab was already integrated with SAML, it managed to perform login and logout.

I already clone that VM and create the new VM and reconfigure it to Gitlab community version and managed to integrate with SAML.
However, during logout, the new VM was redirecting to the old VM IP address.

I already configured the logout syntax at gitlab.rb as per below:

`idp_slo_target_url' => 'https://abc.com.au/idpaa/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php','`

From the log, I saw below message:
`Redirected to https://10.1.7.11:8443/gitlab/users/auth/saml/spslo`

May I know is there any other place that makes the new VM is pointing to the old gitlab URL?

I already grep in the new server, but I cant find any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

During my investigation, I find out that the value is being stored in the postgresql database for gitlab.
I update the table and restart gitlab.
It work accordingly.